# Visual Studio 2012 Express highlight matching braces from both directions

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I've recently switched from Codeblocks to Visual Studio and there are several things are hard to get on with.
The most problematic one is though VS finally has matching braces highlight when you put cursor near them, it only works if you put if Before the brace. If cursor is put After it, no highlighting occurs and that drives me mad sometimes.
I know that this isn't a kind of vital feature but it can make my life much easier, so I am here asking if maybe someone knows how to solve that little but nasty behavior of VS.

Comment: Speaking of brackets I use [this](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=2gua.rainbow-brackets) to make it a little more clear which brackets match up.  Also it should highlight matching brackets if you hover ~directly~ over the bracket.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will definitely check this whenever I will switch to non-express version of VS, but seems like in express you can not use 3rd party extensions.